# How to build Python project completely offline?

Tags: python

I have a task to build several python libraries from sources completely offline. For example following library:
git clone --depth 1 --branch astroid-2.3.3 https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid.git

But when I am doing offline:

```
pip install .
```

I got following error:

```
pip install .
Processing /home/katya/work/prostor/libs2/astroid
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-s61s_95q/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-s61s_95q/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ic09b3i9                                                                         
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-s61s_95q/                                                                                                                   
    Complete output (39 lines):                                                                                                                              
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab9a8ba130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/pytest-runner/   
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab9a8e7760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/pytest-runner/   
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab9a8e71f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/pytest-runner/   
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab9a8e7a00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/pytest-runner/   
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab9a7ef580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/pytest-runner/   
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-runner                                                                             
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest-runner                                                                                                  
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                       
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 119, in fetch_build_egg                                                            
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)                                                                                                                           
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call                                                                                       
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)                                                                                                               
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpptt4cnms', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                             
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                             
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                       
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                   
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-s61s_95q/setup.py", line 53, in <module>                                                                                      
        install()                                                                                                                                            
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-s61s_95q/setup.py", line 32, in install                                                                                       
        return setup(                                                                                                                                        
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup                                                                       
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)                                                                                                                       
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires                                                     
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)                                                                                                           
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 686, in fetch_build_eggs                                                                
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(                                                                                                  
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve                                                                  
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(                                                                                                               
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match                                                              
        return self.obtain(req, installer)                                                                                                                   
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain                                                                  
        return installer(requirement)                                                                                                                        
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 745, in fetch_build_egg                                                                 
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)                                                                                                                    
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 121, in fetch_build_egg                                                            
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e                                                                                                                  
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpptt4cnms', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.                                                                                              
    ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                 
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/katya/work/prostor/libs2/astroid. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.                                                                                                                                               
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Could you tell me how to build this library completely offline?

Comment: you need to be online to install packages from pip, you can then disconnect

Comment: @SuperStew I need to be offline in build time

Comment: You are trying to access an *online* repository. That simply cannot be done *offline*. You can fetch the requirements while being online, then go offline to build/install the final library, but you must be online at some point.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I need to create a GIT repository with everything for offline builds (of the specific libraries)

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what your goal is? Since you fetch the code from an *online* git repository, you can apparently work online. Assuming your destination is offline, is there any reason why you don't fetch and build everything while online then merely move the result (not the source) to the destination?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I do not know about reason, because I am not a Python developer. I just got task "to build offline from sources"

Comment: Download the zip file, extract it and then try `pip install file://path_to_your_extracted_folder`

Comment: @not_speshal which zip do you mean??